# PHP RegEX is not working 100%

Tags: php, regex

It seems like my RegEX isn't working 100% since i added a Space, it dosent work for example when i enter a - it gives me no matches back.

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._ -+]+$/",$parameter)
```

But + works, any idea?

Thanks.

Edit: Fix, thanks guys.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._\s\+\-]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample text string that you're trying to match. What works/what doesn't work.  Also may want to try escaping the -

Comment: Put the `-` at the end of the square brackets.

Comment: im not regex expert, but isnt the `+` after `]` means to match one or more ??

Comment: @Andrew: No. But the unescaped hyphen in the middle creates a range. It matches `!"#$%&')(*+`

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for the clearance :)

Comment: You should unescape some special characters like comma, - etc. Use this : preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._\s\-\+]+$/",$parameter)

Comment: use \s instead of space.

Comment: @greamko If only horizontal space is meant, a regular space can be replaced with `\h` in PHP regex. The only character that should be escaped in the current regex is the `-`. If it is placed at the start or end of the character class, it does not have to be escaped. It is interesting that if you replace a space with `\h`, the `-` does not have to be escaped again as a range cannot be created between a literal character and a shorthand class, or another range delimiters.

Comment: @user235966 To be clear, you just to not have `-` in the pattern. It is a functional character there. Put it at the end. Or replace the space with `\h`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i got it working now.

Comment: `a-zA-Z0-9_` can be replaced with `\w`. So could make regex.. `[\w\s.+-]`. The `-` only needs to be escaped if it isn't the last or first character. Other regex formats don't support the escaping (such as POSIX) so it's best to just have it at the start or end.